# How to prevent the warning message when I open Visio from web with local file from the file system

Tags: c#, web, office-addins, visio

Once I open Visio from web with local file from the file system with the following command:

```
window.location.href = "ms-visio:ofv|u|file://C:/mpsEmptyVisio.vsdx";
```

from: [Office URI Schemes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes)

I getting the following warning message:

[image: Warning Message]

Comment: Yes, this is security prompt. What is the question?

Comment: I need to prevent this prompt (with no change for any end user).

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible (built-in it is security safeguard)

Comment: But from remote URL i didn't getting this message, only from local URL. Why?

Comment: Because it's consider safe source (probably your sharepoint is in your "trusted" or "intranet" site lists). Local computer is not safe source. You could try adding the folder where your diagrams are stored to the organization's safe source lists. Not sure if it will work but maybe worth trying.